# Q: How to display radio horizontally and not vertically on Circuit

Tags: circuit-sdk

I am sending a form to Circuit. But I would like the radio buttons to be displayed horizontally and no vertical.

```
...   form.controls.push({            
          type: 'LABEL',
          text: '<b>' + intents + '</b>'
        },{            
          name: intents,
          type: 'RADIO',
          options: [
              {text:'1', value:'1'},
              {text:'2', value:'2'},
              {text:'3', value:'3'},
              {text:'4', value:'4'},
              {text:'5', value:'5'}
            ]
        }) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported to keep the visual design simple and predictable.